# Brand name whose amount is increasing every year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with three columns year, brand, amount and I want a query that return records of brand whose amount is increasing for every year.

I have pasted below the sample input data and expected output data.

table format:

| year_v | Brand | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | P&G | 50000 |
| 2019 | P&G | 45000 |
| 2020 | P&G | 60000 |
| 2018 | IBM | 55000 |
| 2019 | IBM | 60000 |
| 2020 | IBM | 70000 |
| 2018 | EY | 80000 |
| 2019 | EY | 40000 |
| 2020 | EY | 36000 |

Expected output:

| year_v | Brand | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | IBM | 55000 |
| 2019 | IBM | 60000 |
| 2020 | IBM | 70000 |

As for IBM, amount is increasing every year.

Comment: What version of MySQL? Also, why did you tag your question with plsql?

Comment: 8.0.26 is my MYsql version and plsql tag removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM brands
WHERE brand in
    (SELECT brand
     FROM
       (SELECT brand,
               (amount - lag(amount, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY brand
                                                 ORDER BY year_v)) diff
        FROM brands) t
     GROUP BY brand
     HAVING min(diff) > 0) ;
```

> lag(): LAG (scalar_expression [,offset] [,default])   OVER ( [
> partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )

*There may be scope for refactoring this query, but I will leave it to the OP to decide.*

---

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tjMbBaaYcvwDJ6nrZqaQR2/1)